# Call to a member function get() on null - LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Seeking for your help again. Just wondering for any idea's to return something if the column is NULL. Please see below codes: Thank you!

**Application Controller**

```
 public function index()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $applications = application::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->first()->get();

        if (empty($applications)) {
            return redirect(route('user.application.index'))->with('message','Application is Succesfully');;
        }
        else{
        return view('user.application.index',compact('applications'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't do `->first()->get()`. `first()` does a `get()` internally.

Comment: Hi Guys, before it was only         $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $applications = application::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->first()->get(); Then I tried to add the if else statement. Whenever I remove get I got error on my for loop in blade.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user is not authenticated then you will get unexpected error. So first check the `auth` as `Auth::check()`

Try this :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    public function index()
        {
            if(!Auth::check()) {
                   return view('login');
            }

            $applications = Application::where('user_id', $Auth::user()->id)->first();
            if (empty($applications)) {
                return redirect(route('user.application.index'))->with('message','Application is Succesfully');;
            }
            else{
            return view('user.application.index',compact('applications'));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Talha, Thank you, but I'm getting Auth error even importing use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I got it now. Thank you!